# how to enable zsh completion of path with hyphenated words

Tags: zsh, zshrc

**The setup**

I have my code repos in folder `~/code`.

Suppose I have these repos:

```
~/code/my-repo-awesome
~/code/my-repo-bad
~/code/my-repo-cool
```

ZSH has nice ability to complete paths.

For example, if I write the following

```
cd /u/bi/lo
```

then zsh will complete as follows:

```
cd /usr/bin/local
```

**Question**

Is it possible to configure zsh such that after typing the following

```
cd ~/co/m-r-c
```

it will complete to

```
cd ~/code/my-repo-cool
```

If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `matcher-list` tag.

```
zstyle ':completion:*' matcher-list '' 'r:|-=* r:|=*'
```

For reference: http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Completion-System.html#index-matcher_002dlist_002c-completion-style